# FadeOut for same link that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want with click on each link, after click on button `ok` in `myalert()` same link is `fadeOut()`. if clicked on cancel, is not `fadeOut()`. How can fix it with use of function `myalert()` ?

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/11/

```
function myalert() {
    var result = true;
    //var hide = $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
    //var css = $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');
    var $alertDiv = $('<div class="alert">Do you want to delete this item?<button class="ok">ok</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></div>');
    $('body').append($alertDiv);
    $('.ok').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'none');
        callback(true);
    });
    $('.cancel').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'none');
        callback(false);
    });
    $alertDiv.fadeIn(100);
    $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'block');
    return result;
};

$('.iu').click(myalert)

function callback(result) {
    //
    if (result) {
        $(this).fadeOut('slow');//I mean, this part from code
    } else {
        alert('no')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your callback implementation to also pass along the value of the link that was clicked ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/15/)).

```
function myalert() {
    var result = true;
    //var hide = $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
    //var css = $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');
    var $alertDiv = $('<div class="alert">Do you want to delete this item?<button class="ok">ok</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></div>');

    var link = this; //save the clicks link
    $('body').append($alertDiv);
    $('.ok').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'none');
        callback(true, link); //pass along the clicked link
    });
    $('.cancel').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'none');
        callback(false, link);
    });
    $alertDiv.fadeIn(100);
    $('#appriseOverlay').css('display', 'block');
    return result;
};

$('.iu').click(myalert)

function callback(result, link) {
    if (result) {
        $(link).fadeOut('slow');//fade out the clicked link
    } else {
        alert('no')
    }
}
```

Comment: How can use from 2 click with result different on this function? see: http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/20/

Comment: You have two functions in the same scope with the same name, meaning all you did was overwrite the first definition with the second. Just use the same callback function (like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/22/)) or actually pass the callback as a param to the myalert.

Comment: Did can not use they separate?

Comment: I have no idea what that means; but I'm guessing you mean have different callbacks? In which case you would need to pass the function you wanted as a callback to the myalert function.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of knowing what element you clicked on in the `callback` function:

```
// pass e (the event object to "myalert")
function myalert(e) {
    var result = true;
        //var hide = $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        //var css = $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');
        var $alertDiv = $('<div class="alert">Do you want to delete this item?<button class="ok">ok</button><button class="cancel">cancel</button></div>');
    $('body').append($alertDiv);
    $('.ok').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');

        // pass the clicked element to the callback function
        callback(true, e.target);

    });
    $('.cancel').click(function () {
        $('.alert').fadeOut(100);
        $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','none');

        // pass the clicked element to the callback function
        callback(false, e.target);

    });
    $alertDiv.fadeIn(100);
    $('#appriseOverlay').css('display','block');
return result;
};

$('.iu').click(myalert) // the event object will be passed to myalert

// takes the result, and the clicked element
function callback(result, el) {
    //
    if(result){
       $(el).fadeOut('slow'); 
    }else{
       alert('no')
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/swatkins/fLSeD/

Comment: How can use from 2 click with result different? see: http://jsfiddle.net/MaGyp/20/

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Can you elaborate more?